# Django import excel file using openpyxl

Tags: django, excel

I want to add an excel file to my model 
My view code is like this by using openpyxl :

```
def excel_import(request):
uploadform=UploadFileForm(None)
if request.method == 'POST' :
    uploadform = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if uploadform.is_valid():
        file = uploadform.cleaned_data['docfile']
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=file, read_only=True)

        first_sheet = workbook.get_sheet_names()[0]
        worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(first_sheet)

        data = []

        for row in worksheet.iter_rows(row_offset=1): # Offset for header

                stock = Stocks()
                stock.user = request.user
                stock.name = row[0].value
                stock.number = row[1].value
                stock.suffix = row[2].value
                stock.brand = row[3].value
                stock.comment = row[4].value
                stock.price = row[5].value
                stock.date = datetime.today()
                stock.confirm = 'approved'
                stock.seller = row[7].value
                data.append(stock)

            # Bulk create data
        Stocks.objects.bulk_create(data)


return render(request, 'BallbearingSite/news.html',{'uploadform':uploadform})
```

the problem is it add some extra empty rows to the database .
what is the problem with codes ? How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it runs into empty rows in the excel before stopping. Get the number of the last row.

```
wb=Workbook()
ws=wb.active
last_row=ws.max_row
```

Now run loop through the excel file using last_row as maximum number